# How to increase visa duration as Indian travlling to Kazakhstan?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-extensions, kazakhstan

Indian citizens can go visa-free to Kazakhstan, but suppose I want to stay there for longer. How can I extend the visa for longer duration, say 2 months?

Comment: Has that changed recently? According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&modify=1) nationals of India with a normal passport can enter for a maximum stay of 14 days, with a maximum stay of 42 days within 180 days.

Comment: By applying for an actual visa?

Answer (score 3):

Indian citizens [can enter](https://www.gov.kz/memleket/entities/mfa-delhi?lang=en) Kazakhstan visa-free for 14 days per entry, up to a total of 42 days in an 180-day period.

If you plan to stay for up to 30 days, you can apply for [a Kazakh e-visa](https://www.gov.kz/memleket/entities/mfa/press/article/details/6720?directionId=3053&lang=en). E-visas require a Kazakh citizen to invite you (this can be a travel agency or organized tour if you do not know anyone in Kazakhstan) and can only be used when entering the country at Nur-Sultan or Almaty airport. The e-visa is *not* extendable beyond 30 days.

If even 30 days is not enough, you can try [applying for a visa through the embassy of Kazakhstan in New Delhi](https://www.gov.kz/memleket/entities/mfa-delhi/activities/6176?lang=en&parentId=5648), though I doubt they will be willing to grant longer than 30-day stays. (The Kazakh embassy in Washington [says they only grant 30-day stays](https://www.gov.kz/memleket/entities/mfa-washington/press/article/details/13581?directionId=5896&lang=en) for tourists, for example.) Tourist visas (class B12) [are not extendible](https://egov.kz/cms/en/services/for_foreigners/pass597_mvd) while in the country.

Your best bet may be to visit Kazakhstan for 14 or 30 days without or with a visa, move on to another country (e.g., Kyrgyzstan, which issues e-visas to Indian citizens), and then, if you wish, return to Kazakhstan for another 14-day stay, as long as you do not exceed the 42-days-in-180 limit. I am unable to find any way that an Indian citizen can stay in Kazakhstan for tourism purposes for longer than that.